# Moving away a field-label from its Combo-box

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a combobox that i'm trying to move it away from its fieldLabel, however i'm not being successful any help on this matter?

```
period_duration = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        store: period,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbr',
        allowBlank:false,
        margin:'0 0 0 145',
        fieldLabel: "${ts.language}" == "AR" ? '<span style="font-size: 17px; margin:0 0 0 0; padding: 5 5 5 5">\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0632\u0645\u0646\u064a\u0629</span>' : '<span style="font-size: 13px; padding: 5 5 5 5">Date Range</span>',
        id:'type',
        editable:false,
        width: 460,

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a config 'labelWidth' to comboBox which you can use to set width of fieldLabel. So if you give more labelWidth, your comboBox will move away from fieldLabel .  This width will be taken from width you have given to combo.

e.g If you give combo width as 500 and labelWidth as 200 then label will take width as 200 and remaining comboBox will get width as (500 - 200) = 300

Answer (score 0):

Use `labelStyle` config:

```
var labelStyleAr = {
        'font-size': '17px',
        margin: '0',
        padding: '5'
    },
    labelStyleAr = {
        'font-size': '13px',
        padding: '5'
    };

period_duration = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    ....
        labelStyle: "${se.language}" == "AR" ? labelStyleAr : labelStyle,
        fieldLabel: "${se.language}" == "AR" ? '\u0627\u0644\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0632\u0645\u0646\u064a\u0629' : 'Date Range',    
    });
```